# RMI - Remote Objects - Design question

Tags: java, rmi

I have been reading through the Java tutorial on RMI. I like the approach that is outlined here for implementing a remote interface:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/implementing.html

What I would like to know are 2 things:

1) With regard to the `executeTask` method outlined in the aforementioned link, how would this design allow Remote Objects (tasks) access some sort of global state if the ComputeEngine is just calling the execute method of a Task?

2) Would this design be suitable for a multi-threaded environment?

Thanks indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ad. 1:** Please note that remote client does not know anything about `ComputeEngine` class, only the `Compute` interface. Also, the server implementation might change completely, but if the interface does not change, client shouldn't notice. If you want to pass some *context* to the task coming from remote client, do it on interface layer:

```
public class ComputeEngine implements Compute {

private GlobalContext globalContext = //...

public <T> T executeTask(Task<T> t) {
    return t.execute(globalContext);
}
```

This way each task has access to the `globalContext` and knows exactly what to expect from `globalContext` (what are the server capabilities, the *context*). `GlobalContext` would be a JavaBean or more likely some service interface.

On the client side it might look like this

```
Compute compute = //obtain RMI client stub somehow
compute.executeTask(new Task<String>() {
    public String execute(GlobalContext globalContext) {
        //Note that this code is executed on the server and
        //getFoo() is implemented on the server side. We only know its interface
        globalContext.getFoo();
        //...
    }
}
```

**Ad. 2:** It will *work* with multiple clients calling the service concurrently. However it is up to you to implement the server in thread-safe manner. The example from tutorial you mentioned in thread-safe, but my code using `GlobalContext` might not be. Please notice that several clients will use the same instance of `globalContext` concurrently, which might, but does not have to cause some issues. That's probably the most interesting part.

And finally remember that receiving unknown `Task` from remote client and running it on server is very impressive, but not quite safe.

Comment: Hi Tomasz, great reply. Thanks for that. Just with regard to the first answer, how will a task be able to access 'globalContext' if it is a ComputeEngine private instance variable? Would it not be better if this was static? thanks again.

Comment: I added clarifying example, hope it helps.